# Div on the left side of an image

Tags: css, layout, html, image

I have a div with several other divs inside it.

I would like to place a an image to the right side of this div.

I've tried all types `float:left;` `clear:both;`....  but does not work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/10/) you can see the complete code of the page.

The div marked in blue, will be on the left, the img marked in red, should be on the right side of the blue div.

P.S. The image is not available, so it will display alternative text, but this should not be important.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you want?

Comment: course, but where do I save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `float:left;` to `div#waycontact` so it can be in the flow of the structure.

See updated updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/AsxXy/)

Comment: if you do, both the image and the div id=content will go to the right.

Comment: You will also need to float and clear other elements to fix that. In my example I've also edited `#logo` and `#content`. I've noticed you have used ids where you should be using classes as you seem to hvae used `#content` a few times

Comment: Add `clear: both;` to `div#content` to make it go back under `div#waycontact`. (Sorry, I hadn't seen the other comments.)

Answer (score 3):

Float `#waycontact` to the left:

```
div#waycontact {
    width:300px;
    margin:20px 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

Then float `#logo` to the left and give it a `margin-top` to match `#waycontact`:

```
img#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Then add a clearing `<div>` immediately after `#logo` to clean up the floats:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CdqJk/1/

(Original backwards version below)

<s>First, move `#id` above `#waycontact` in the HTML. Then:</s>

```
img#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px; /* to match #waycontact[margin-top] */
}
div#waycontact {
    width:300px;
    margin:20px 40px 20px 100px;
}
```

The `margin-left:100px` on `#waycontact` is to make enough room for the `#logo`, the real margin value will depend on how big the logo image really is.

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CdqJk/

Comment: @Riderman: Sorry, had it backwards, have a look at my update, I think I have the correct right/left order now.

Answer (score 2):

float `#waycontact` left. and then make sure the `#content` clears

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/85unG/16/)**